# PHP foreach loop array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a script where it's displaying user info on a leader board. It's grabbing each user's display info through the 'registrations' table as shown in the top sql, however their back-end info (username, user id, ip address etc) is stored in the 'users' table. The registrations table has a column 'user_id', which I'm trying to link with the users table which can be seen after the `foreach`.

The goal is to have the username (stored in 'users') to be displayed for each user - which is shown at `<td class='center'>" . $userdata['username'] . "</td>`. However, the username isn't displaying.

At the bottom, I'm trying to insert a record to another table which also uses this same username value, however it inserts as an empty string. Please note the `INSERT` should only insert for the user that was clicked on.. can this even be achieved?

-Also, I am aware this PHP isn't the best and should be using prepared statements etc, however that is not the current goal at the moment.

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM registrations LIMIT 5");

foreach ($sql as $row)
{
    $userdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" . $row['user_id'] . "'"));
    echo "
                    <tr class='gradeX'>
                        <td class='center'>" . $userdata['username'] . "</td>
                        <td class='center'>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>
                        <td class='center'>" . $row['wins'] . " - " . $row['losses'] . "</td>
            <td class='center'><form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='invite' value='Request Game'/></form></td>
                        <td class='center'><a href='' class='btn btn-success'>WATCH STREAM</a></td>
                    </tr>";
}

if (isset($_POST['invite']))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO matches (id,sender,receiver,time,console,rank_sender,rank_receiver,status) values ('0', '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "', '" . $userdata['username'] . "', '" . time() . "', '" . $row['type'] . "', '" . $GETD['rank'] . "', '$rank', 'pending')";
    mysqli_query($DB, $query);
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why you didn't take directly all data from your first query? Then in your loop, you just have to display the data of a row

Comment: You need to do `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to loop for first query also.

Comment: @Eiji, the data is from 2 different tables so I'm unsure how you would do this in one query, would using `INNER JOIN` work?

Comment: Yes of course. I don't know your table but it seems like the `INNER JOIN users ON users.id = registrations.user_id` be something close to your DB.

Comment: `foreach ($sql as $row)` doesn't make much sense, as that's the query-object, and not any fetched data.

Comment: @Qirel , would `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {` be a better option for this then?

Comment: `$sql = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM registrations JOIN users on on users.id=registrations.user_id LIMIT 5");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
foreach($res as $row){

}` you should use `JOIN` in the query, then fetch the result and then loop it.

Comment: Agree with @quirel. You can replace foreach($sql as $row) with while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))

Comment: In your `INSERT` query, you are trying to use `$userdata` and `$row` which are outside the scope of the `foreach` as well since it's inserted after submit (`POST`) you need to pass those values at least with your form submission. You can use hidden form fields to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `JOIN`, you can execute a single query and fetch the data you need. I also converted this to using a prepared statement - which should be used over the standard `mysqli::query()` method, even without variables in the query.

Your `INSERT` query quite doesn't make sense (judging by the variables you had in your question), so you should have a look at the variables and set them as they should be (your code in the question would insert the username of the *last* fetched username, and that is not necessarily the value you expect it to be).

I also removed your `id` from the `INSERT` query, this should instead be an auto-increment in your `matches` table.

You need to assign the proper values to the lines with `TODO` in the appending comment of that line.

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT u.username, r.balance, r.wins, r.losses
                      FROM registrations r 
                      JOIN users u 
                        ON u.id=r.user_id
                      LIMIT 5
                      ");
$stmt->bind_result($username, $balance, $wins, $losses);
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <tr class='gradeX'>
        <td class='center'><?php echo $username; ?></td>
        <td class='center'><?php echo $balance; ?></td>
        <td class='center'><?php echo $wins; ?> - <?php echo $losses; ?></td>
        <td class='center'>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='invite' value='Request Game'/>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td class='center'><a href='' class='btn btn-success'>WATCH STREAM</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
}
$stmt->close();

if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {
    // Assign the variables here. 
    $username_sender = 'somevalue';  // TODO: Define this. 
    $time = time();
    $rank_sender = $GETD['rank'];
    $rank_receiver = $rank;          // TODO: Define this. 
    $console = $type;                // TODO: Define this. 
    $status = 'pending';

    $stmt = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO matches (sender, receiver, time, console, rank_sender, rank_receiver, status)
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $_SESSION['username'], $username_sender, $time, $console, $rank_sender, $rank_receiver, $status);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

- [PHP.net on `mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare)
- [PHP.net on `mysqli::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Amazing! Thankyou so much. I seem to get an error however, `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_result() on bool in ~~~~~ Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ~~~~~~~`. Would you happen to know the cause for this?

Comment: The `prepare()` failed. Print out `$DB->error;` and `$stmt->error;`

Comment: `Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in ~~~~~ on line 82`

Comment: Did `$DB->error` give anything? What is the ID column named in the `users` table?

Comment: My goodness.. turn's out the id column in user's is user_id and not id like I thought, I'm an idiot. I got it working! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Glad to have helped! I recommend you take a moment to read up on how these prepared statements work, and incorporate it throughout all your queries. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have done improvements to your code. I didn't make much change for your easy  understanding. I am trying to give you some hints, on passing variables in a post request (like form submission).

Note: retrieved post values must be sanitized before use in the query. You may use prepared statements to do so after you have understood this answer.

```
    <?php
$sql = mysqli_query($DB, "
  SELECT * FROM registrations
  JOIN users on users.id=registrations.user_id
   WHERE users.id='" . $row['user_id'] . "' LIMIT 5");

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "
<tr class='gradeX'>
    <td class='center'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
    <td class='center'>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>
    <td class='center'>" . $row['wins'] . " - " . $row['losses'] . "</td>
    <td class='center'>
        <form method='post' action=''>
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='invite' value='Request Game'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='username' value='". $row['username'] . "' />
        <input type='hidden' name='type' value='". $row['type'] . "' />
        </form>
    </td>
    <td class='center'><a href='' class='btn btn-success'>WATCH STREAM</a></td>
</tr>";
}

if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO matches (id,sender,receiver,time,console,rank_sender,rank_receiver,status) values ('0', '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "', '" . $_POST['username'] . "', '" . time() . "', '" . $_POST['type'] . "', '" . $GETD['rank'] . "', '$rank', 'pending')";
    mysqli_query($DB, $query);
}
```